# Smudge filter lfs failed when cloning Visual Studio Online Git repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-lfs

I'm trying to use [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) with a [Visual Studio Online](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/01/announcing-git-lfs-on-all-vso-git-repos/) Git repository to store code alongside some large CSV data files.

I downloaded the git-lfs installer, restarted git-bash, ran `git lfs install`, cloned an empty repo, and ran `git lfs track "*.csv"`. Then I committed code and CSV files, and ran `git push origin master`. I got this warning:

```
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config 'lfs.https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_git/reponame.git/info/lfs.locksverify' false
Git LFS: (0 of 0 files, 135 skipped) 0 B / 0 B, 3.75 GB skipped                
Counting objects: 261, done.
```

Then I tried to clone the repo to a fresh directory, to see if it's working. I get these errors:

```
Downloading data/data.csv (738.83 MB)
Error downloading object: data/data.csv(**********************************************47505bb25a3e2a552e)

error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed 2
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed
fatal: data/data.csv: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get git-lfs to work with a VSO Git repository?

Comment: Have you tried to disable the support to LFS locking API using the "git config" command as suggested?

Comment: Yes. I've tried it after after the initial git push.

Comment: And have you done the push again?

Comment: Yes, but there are no code change, so nothing to push.

Comment: Change something just to make the push possible and know if the data.csv will be pushed to LFS correctly.

Comment: I still get the original error

Comment: What is your LFS version (git lfs version)?

Comment: git-lfs/2.0.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.8; git 540e90b5)

Comment: It seems that you have not executed the "git config" command correctly (have you received an error?) because file locking was not disabled correctly. See more info about the file locking new feature here: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/File-Locking. Check the "git config" command and your .gitconfig file, I think there's something to be adjusted. See also the "locks" and "unlock" commands. Another alternative: you could downgrade your git lfs (1.x.x).

Comment: When I run git config -l, it does show lfs.https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_git/reponame.git/info/lfs.locksverify=false present . And the lfs files are showing on the server (with the lfs sha256 codes as content). The warning no longer appears upon git push. But the error upon git clone is still present.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below steps:

1.Check if `.gitattributes` are also version controlled by git. And if it has the content:

```
*.csv filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs –text
```

2.Use the command

```
git config 'lfs.https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_git/reponame.git/info/lfs.locksverify' false
```

and double check by `git config-l`, and also check if git config contains:

```
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
```

3. Commit some changes and push again, you will find there is no such warnings. And clone again.